# TYPO3 can't file template file for Backend Layout (Sitepackage Builder)

Tags: typo3

I am using TYPO3 11.5.25 with the Sitepackage Builder / Bootstrap Package.

I have created a custom Backend Layout in my custom sitepackage extension which was working fine. After uploading the extensions (bootstrap package and sitepackage) to my web server the Backend Layout is not working and outputting the following error:

> Tried resolving a template file for controller action "Standard->customHomepage" in format ".html", but none of the paths contained the expected template file (Standard/customHomepage.html). The following paths were checked: .../htdocs/custom.de/typo3conf/ext/bootstrap_package/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/, .../htdocs/custom.de/typo3conf/ext/custom/Resources/Private/Templates/Page/

I have checked the location of the error output and the file exists. The Sitepackage has also been included in the Template settings. The other layouts provided by Bootstrap package are working fine.

The backend layout is setup in page properties.

What could be the problem?

EDIT: I have tried to change the file names of the template file to 1.html. Now it seems to work... But now they have different file names and it is hard to keep files synced. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Just to be sure (because of a usual error): your EXT:custom is activated/installed? An existing file won't be found, if TYPO3 is not allowed to use an extension.

Comment: Yes its installed of course - also see the "EDIT": After renaming it is working. It is still placed in the same ext.

Comment: Have you considered that the web server usually has a case-sensitive file system, but on the local machine it is often insensitive?